# how to CRUD using Polymorphic Relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, polymorphism

I have 2 types of post : simple post and blog articles 
and I want to relate it to comments via Polymorphic Relations

this is my models :

```
// Comment Model 
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');
}


//Article and Simple post Model 

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

Ehat's the best way to use create comment and store the correct value of the Class name of each type in `commentable_type` and the id

```
    $comment = Auth::User()->comment();
    $comment->content = $request->input('content');
    $comment->commentable_id = $request->input(?);
    $comment->commentable_type = $request->input(?);
    $comment->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, you should create the Comment through the comentable Model (i.e: Post, SimplePost) [check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models):

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['content' => $request->input('content')]);
$post = Post::find($request->input('post_id'));
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Comment: I want to use get_class method to get the type of $post (simple or article)
how can i pass this parametre ??

Comment: @acharmat well if you know from the frontend if you're working on an article or a post, just send a parameter like post_type=post then in the code: `if ($request->input('post_id') == 'post') {
   $post = Post::find($request->input('post_id'));
} else {
  $post = Article::find($request->input('post_id'));
}
// the rest of the code
`